# Counting number of swaps by comparing adjacent elements in an array

Tags: c++

I am trying to count number of swaps to sort the given array in ascending order. Inside the for loop I have a if condition to check the condition weather to swap or not , But inside if condition I have added a `cout` statement to check which elements are being compared, When I have that `cout` statement number of swaps printed are different, and when I remove that statement number of swaps printed are different, for sample:

**if I have cout statement**

Sample Input

```
1

4

4 1 2 3
```

**and output came as**

```
3
```

**if I remove or comment that cout statement**

Sample Input

```
1

4

4 1 2 3
```

**and output came as**

```
4
```

I can't figure out the reason for this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int swap=0,t,n,arr[20],temp;
    cin>>t;
    while(t!=0) {
      cin>>n;
      for(int  i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
         cin>>arr[i];
      }
      for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]) {
          swap++;
          cout<<arr[i]<<">"<<arr[i+1]<<endl; //this cout statement
          temp=arr[i];
          arr[i]=arr[i+1];
          arr[i+1]=temp;
        }
      }
      cout<<swap<<endl;
      --t; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `arr[i+1]` is out of bound if I don't get it wrong.

Comment: What will be value of arr[i+1] in last iteration of loop, i.e. i=n-1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is non-deterministic since you are accessing a position of the array that should not be accessed, i.e. when i = n - 1, a[i+1] is trying to access a[n] that is "dirty" memory. 
Furthermore I think that your algorithm does not do what you want it to do. I suggest you to read [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) before going further. From the right code, it's enough to add the counter (as you did) to obtain the correct result.